# sprintf and uint64_t not formated correctly using PRIu64

Tags: c, format, printf

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uint64_t delta = (some huge number);
char outstring[80];
sprintf(outstring, "Delta of %"PRIu64 " seconds detected. Adjusting RTC\r\n", delta);
```

This results in outstring = 
"Delta of lu seconds detected. Adjusting RTC"

obviously I'm looking for the number in outstring not "lu".  What piece of syntax am I not understanding now?

I'm using gcc c11 I think

Comment: If you are using a mingw-w64 gcc, read [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/printf%20and%20scanf%20family/) for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C library `printf` does not seem to support `long long` types. This is a common shortcoming of older MSVC libraries on Windows, when used in combinations with a port of `gcc`. You should upgrade to a recent version of Microsoft Visual Studio and use that or switch to a platform with better C support such as OS/X or Linux.

Comment: I think mingw provides an optional replacement library for printf and some other broken things in msvcrt which you should use if you're using mingw.